# How to use dynamic name to populate multiple React components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to use the variable to populate multiple React components here:

```
const MyComponent = 'MyComponent'
components.map((item, index) => (<MyComponent {...item} key={`${type}_${index}`} />))
```

But it does not work, through inspecting the returned result, I found that the component **type** was not been assigned explicitly. Meanwhile, if I do not use a variable to define a component name, it works well. The **type** is not even to be a **function** but would be assigned to the real name of the component.

[image]

Comment: What are you expecting the type to be?

Comment: Look at the `props` field in each of those, do they correspond to the values in each `item`?

Comment: where does `type` comes from?

Comment: You need to include the part of the code where `type` is set and also expand the objects in the debug output, so it is possible to see the props.

Comment: The description of my expecting type was appended in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, **MyComponent** should not be a string but points to the component instance